# How do I set the focus on the first input in a form when blurring away from the submit button?

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility

I have the following HTML form:

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" id="input1">
    <input type="text">
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

I want to set the focus on `#input1` when I blur on the Submit button. Here is the JS that I have:

```js
document.querySelector('button').onblur = function() {
  console.log('blurred');
  document.querySelector('#input1').focus();
};
```

I can see the `console.log` happening, but for some reason the focus isn't being set on `#input1`.

Try it here: https://jsbin.com/gukocuyada/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the code works fine. The only problem is the form tries to submit it self. So when we get a blank page after the submit button is hit. You can fix this by listening for an ***onsubmit*** event on the form and then prevent the form from submitting with ***event.preventDefault()***.

Comment: When I hit tab on the Submit button, the focus isn't set on the first input. That is what I'm seeing in Chrome. Are you seeing different?

Comment: Yes that the expected behavior as we are listening for an onblurr event on the submit button. Note: the onblurr event is triggered when any area on the page is clicked after the submit button is hit. Or when the submit is out of focus

Comment: If by "hitting the submit button" you mean, clicking it or pressing Enter, I am not doing that. I am just pressing the tab key when the Submit button has the focus, and the focus is not being set on the first input. If you are seeing that, what browser are you using?

Comment: @Rilla The button is not `type="submit"` so it does not submit the form. `preventDefault()` will not help here.

Comment: Am using chrome. Am actually clicking the button then clicking any empty area on the page and it seems to work for me. Try listening for ***onfocusout*** and see  if it works for your use case

Comment: Since the `<button>` is the last focusable element on the page, when you *<tab>* out of it, the browser will override the `.onblur` handler and simply move the focus to the URL bar. You can confirm this by adding another `<input>` field after the `<button>` and you will see that hitting *<tab>* does indeed focus on the first `<input>` field. So you can kludge around that default browser behavior by adding a fake input field at the end: `<input style="width: 0px; height: 0px; border: none;">`.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `<button>` is the last focusable element on the page, when you  out of it, the browser will override the `.onblur` handler and simply move the focus to the URL bar. This seems to be built in to most browsers (at least Chrome and Firefox).

You can confirm this by adding another `<input>` field after the `<button>` and you will see that hitting  does indeed focus on the first `<input>` field.

You can kludge your way around that default browser behavior by adding a fake input field at the end:

```
<input style="width: 0px; height: 0px; border: none;" onclick="document.querySelector('#input1').focus();">
```